# Request SQL (WITH AS) in Php Pdo on Oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo

I try to execute an request SQL Select.
My request work in SQL Developer but when i copy my request on my code she return 0 result while on SQL Developer return many result.
My connection on my BDD Oracle works.

```
       $sql = $connexion->prepare("With Calcul_Max_Num  as
       (                 
            Select ho_ddeb
                     , ho_manumdos
                     , ho_num
                     , si_nom
                     , si_prenom
                     , si_sexe
                     , si_nais
                     , si_ma_lib1
                     , si_ma_vil
                     , si_ma_codepost
                     , si_ma_tel
                     , sm_incode
                     , in_nom
                     , in_prenom
                     , sm_ddeb
                     , sm_hdeb
                     , sm_unitr
                     , max(ho_ddeb) Over (Partition BY  ho_manumdos ) as Max_Date

         from SERVEUR_MOUVEMENT
               INNER JOIN serveur_identite
               ON sm_numdos = si_numdos
               INNER JOIN HOSPITALISATION
               ON ho_num = sm_numhos
               INNER JOIN INTERVENANT
               ON SM_INCODE = IN_CODE

         Where (SERVEUR_MOUVEMENT.SM_TYPMVT = 'ADM'
         Or SERVEUR_MOUVEMENT.SM_TYPMVT = 'AHJ'
         Or SERVEUR_MOUVEMENT.SM_TYPMVT = 'VPR')
       )
              select  
                      ho_manumdos
                     , ho_num
                     , si_nom
                     , si_prenom
                     , si_sexe
                     , extract(YEAR from si_nais)
                     , to_char(si_nais, 'MM')
                     , to_char(si_nais, 'DD')
                     , si_ma_lib1
                     , si_ma_vil
                     , si_ma_codepost
                     , si_ma_tel
                     , sm_incode
                     , in_nom
                     , in_prenom
                     , to_char(sm_ddeb, 'YY')
                     , to_char(sm_ddeb, 'MM')
                     , to_char(sm_ddeb, 'DD')
                     , to_char(sm_hdeb, 'HH')
                     , to_char(sm_hdeb, 'MI')

         From Calcul_Max_Num 
         Where Max_date Between '01/01/2015' AND '31/12/2015'
         and ho_ddeb = Max_Date
         order by ho_manumdos");




        $sql->execute();
        while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                  echo 'good';
        }
```

I think the problem happens because of the beginning of the request, is it possible to start the request sql by With  as (select .....) ?

Comment: No GROUP BY needed?

Comment: i think no because he work on SQL Developer

Comment: Should that matter?

Comment: yes of course but if you know an another way i take

Comment: confirm that your "request SQL" path is actually "connecting" to the DB and tables you need. Rather than the big query above, make sure that a simple `select count(*) from serveur_identite` (or other) works. Good luck.

Comment: My request SQL work as the connecting to the DB.because when i try with a simple "Select * from .....".  
I think the problem happens because of the beginning of the request, is it possible to start the request sql by With <NAME> as (select .....) ?

Comment: Did you change this line `Where Max_date Between '01/01/2015' AND '31/12/2015'` between testing in SQL Dev and moving the code to PHP Pdo?  What you have here are string values instead of date values being used in your range.  consequently the Max_Date value may be getting converted to a string value using a different format than SQL Dev was using.  Try using the `TO_DATE()` function on each of your "dates": `Where Max_date Between TO_DATE('01/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31/12/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')`

Comment: Ohh guy great job ! Thank you